# Live connection between Power BI Desktop and Online Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, powerbi

i have data in a primary sheet that's a protected sheet where my access is restricted, I am trying to establish a live connection between the sheet and Power BI but I am experiencing difficulties in doing so, is there an alternative for me?

I have copied the sheet link and tried to establish a live web connection between the sheet and power BI but I get error messages, is there another way to do this?